# Send email to a list of users in an array with list of attachments in an array

Tags: bash

I'd like to if possible send a **single email** to a list of users defined in a bash array with a list of files contained in a bash array as well.

```
EMAILS=(email1@email.com email2@email.com)
FILES=(picture1.png picture2.png)
echo "$(date)" | mailx -s "Snapshot for $(date)" ${EMAILS[@]}
```

I got this far but I am stuck on how I would go about attaching the attachments to the email. I know you're supposed to use `-A "PATH_TO_FILE"` but I don't know how to expand the array so that the `-A` is prefixed to each filename.

Currently using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, bash version 4.3.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take help from command substitution and `printf`:

```
$ FILES=(picture1.png picture2.png)

$ echo $(printf -- '-A %s ' "${FILES[@]}")
-A picture1.png -A picture2.png
```

So you need:

```
echo "$(date)" | mailx -s "Snapshot for $(date)" $(printf -- '-A %s ' "${FILES[@]}") "${EMAILS[@]}"
```

Comment: Getting this error:
`mailx:  File1.png -A File2.png -A File3.png -A File4.png : cannot stat: File name too long`

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!